# Why does 22 when converted to a string, with printOn or StoreOn, still add like an integer?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

This is my code:

```
x := 22 storeString.
y := x + x.
Transcript show: y.
```

Expected output: 2222
Actual output: 44.

I thought that the `storeString` message, sent to 22, assigned to x, would result in a string value being stored into x.

So I thought, I'm pretty new in smalltalk. Maybe it's order of operations? So I tried this:

```
x := (22 storeString).
y := x + x.
Transcript show: y.
```

Same result, and same, if I use `printOn` instead of `storeOn`.  This is probably a day-one tutorial-following type question. But what is going on?  Note that I know about the concatenation operator (,) but I am still wondering how it is that you can add two strings together like this?  Is some implicit conversion from string back to integer happening as part of `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#+` is implemented on `String` and does a coercion to a `Number` before doing the addition.

Squeak has lot of eToys (a Smalltalk variation for kids) code spread throughout its core codebase. This is likely the reason why `String` implements all math operators. In Pharo the math operators have been mostly removed from `String`, so `'1' + '2'` raises an error like in any other Smalltalk.

Comment: That makes sense to me now. The fruit-loop colored toys are not visible (instances running) on the default VM in squeak any more (it looks pretty pro and vanilla) but the internal image bits remain.

Answer (score 4):

Only a few things are implicit in Smalltalk. You can browse the implementation of `#+` selector in String class and find out yourself what is going on. Or print `String >> #+ definition`.
You can also check out the internals of any running object instance, so you could have evaluated `x inspect`, to find out that x really is a String.

Comment: Good point. I was not thinking about it this way, and I can see I have some ways to go in learning to "think more like smalltalk".

Answer (score 3):

Open a workspace. Enter:

'12' + '34'

Highlight and then use the right button menu to invoke "debug it". If ever there was a "killer app" for Smalltlak, it is the way the Smalltalk debugger interacts with the "all objects all the time" nature of Smalltalk. You can see what everything is and how it does. If you use "into", you'll be able to see exactly how it pulls off turning that into '46'.

Even cooler (I think), is that you can do

12 + '34'

(the first is no longer a string, rather a direct number). Again, you can use the debugger, and the whole double dispatch mechanism Smalltalk uses to do transcendental math will be opened up to you.

You can even do weirder examples like

4.0 + #('13'  2)

(here we're adding a number to an array, and the array contents are of mixed type)

Happy Smalltalking!

Comment: Thanks.  This is at my (beginner) level.

Answer (score 2):

this behavior may appear puzzling to anyone not familiar with smalltalk, especially since in other languages the exact opposite tends to happen (numbers are coerced to strings).

the reason why this not a problem, is because string concatenation is done with `,`. once aware of that, it becomes clear that `'22' + 22` or even `'22' + '22'` can never be `'2222'`. it's either going to fail, or produce `44`.

so if string concatenation is what you want, you need to send the right message:

```
x := 22 storeString.
y := x , x.
Transcript show: y.
```